# Multiple hlines by looping through to set threshold levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to create 3 threshold lines across my bar chart, however, each line will only go to the date of the next threshold point and then a new line will start. it is a table of 3 columns, 'Cash', 'End Date', and 'Tenor'

I have the following code, but I cannot get it to loop at those levels and instead the lines are the full width of the graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = {'Cash':[900e6,800e6,700e6,600e6,500e6,400e6,300e6,200e6,100e6,0],
      'End Date': ['27/03/2023','28/03/2023','29/03/2023','30/03/2023','31/03/2023','01/04/2023','02/04/2023','20/09/2023','21/09/2023','21/01/2024'],
      'Tenor': ['1-3 Month','1-3 Month','1-3 Month','1-3 Month','1-3 Month','1-3 Month','1-3 Month','6 Month','6 Month','9Month']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df)
pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 100))
for tenor, group in df.groupby('Tenor'):
    cash_out_limits = [200e6, 300e6, 500e6] # define cash out limits for each tenor
    last_end_date = group.iloc[-1]['End Date'] # get the last end date for each tenor
    start_end_date = group.iloc[0]['End Date']
    print(start_end_date)
    # create a red hline for each cash out limit
    for limit in cash_out_limits:
        ax.axhline(limit, color='r', linestyle='--')

    
# plot cash out vs end date as a bar chart
df.plot(x='End Date', y='Cash', kind='bar', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The next step would to be to create vertical lines at each tenor end down to the next threshold point. I have managed to get the threshold points with last_end_date and start_end_date.

Would someone be able to help.

I have tried editing this line, but it does not work:

```
for limit in cash_out_limits:  
    ax.axhline(y=limit, xmin = start_end_date, xmax = last_end_date, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

[Graph currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlHiV.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fRKy.png)

Comment: I have added the graph

Answer (score 1):

#### Control the width of the horizontal line with the extra parameters

`axhline` has optional 2nd and 3rd parameters which specify xmin and xmax.

```
Axes.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=1, **kwargs)
```

So if you want the horizontal line to be limited, how about this:

```
ax.axhline(y=limit, xmin=10, xmax=20, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

Obviously you will want to replace the 10 and 20 with appropriate values or formulae depending on what you want the x range to be.

Comment: Do you know how i can set xmin and xmax to the levels i want in the loop? Basically the last tenor point in a bucket. e.g. 3mth and 6mth.

When i include them in this no line appears on the graph.

Comment: Aren't they `last_end_date` and `start_end_date`, respectively? I am afraid your mention of `tenor` etc is confusing, especially in the context of reading an external file which we don't have. Can you put _everything_ into a single python file?

Comment: I have updated with data. When i include this it cannot convert into x values

   

`for limit in cash_out_limits:
 ax.axhline(y=limit, xmin = start_end_date, xmax = last_end_date, color='r', linestyle='--')`

Comment: I have also tried to include this line, but then no hlines appear at all:

`df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])`